# The firebase admob banner advertisement is displayed in the upper left. How can I display it at the bottom center of the screen?

Tags: ios, c++11, firebase, admob, cocos2d-x

I would like to display AdMob's banner advertisement on the bottom of the screen using firebase.
Currently, the banner advertisement will be displayed on the screen Left-Top.
I found the following classes and values that are likely to be related from the framework, but I do not know how to use it. Even if I looked at [Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/cpp/cocos2d-x) and [sample](https://github.com/firebase/cocos2dx-cpp-sample) I could not get usage.

firebase :: admob :: BannerView :: Position
firebase :: admob :: BannerView :: kPositionBottom

Please tell me how to display the banner ad on the bottom of the screen.

Development environment
Xcode 9.1
cocos2d-x 3.16
firebase cpp sdk 4.2.0

```
[bool HelloWorld::init(){
if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

// Intitialize Firebase AdMob.
    firebase::admob::Initialize(*firebase::App::GetInstance(), kAdMobAppID);

firebase::admob::BannerView* banner_view = new firebase::admob::BannerView();
firebase::admob::AdSize ad_size;
    ad_size.ad_size_type = firebase::admob::kAdSizeStandard;
    ad_size.width = 320;
    ad_size.height = 50;
banner_view->Initialize(getAdParent(), kAdViewAdUnit, ad_size);
this->scheduleUpdate();

return true;
}


void HelloWorld::update(float delta)
{
    // Check that the banner has been initialized.
    if (banner_view->InitializeLastResult().status() ==firebase::kFutureStatusComplete)
    {
        // Check that the banner hasn't started loading.
        if (banner_view->LoadAdLastResult().status() == firebase::kFutureStatusInvalid)
        {
            // Make the banner visible and load an ad.
            CCLOG("Loading a banner.");
            banner_view->Show();
            firebase::admob::AdRequest my_ad_request = {};
            banner_view->LoadAd(my_ad_request);
        }
    }
}]
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3ya2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're calling [moveTo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/class/firebase/admob/banner-view#moveto), which is the BannerView method that changes the banner's position. There's a version that takes the constant you mentioned (kPositionBottom), and a version that takes an (x,y) pair.

Comment: Thank you!
It was able to display on the bottom!